# Error detected in pubspec.yaml: Duplicate mapping key

Tags: flutter, calendar

I get the following error:
Error on line 41, column 3: Duplicate mapping key.
╷
41 │   syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^20.1.57
│   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

but my line 41 is

```
 dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
41      sdk: flutter
      flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
```

Thanks in advance

Full code is this and

```
name: x
description: x

publish_to: 'none' 

 
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^20.1.57
 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  table_calendar: ^3.0.5
 
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
 
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "images/launcher_icon.png"

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
 
flutter:
 
  uses-material-design: true
 

  assets:
    - images/
```

Comment: I just copied your code, it works fine. Try quitting your text editor and opening it again.

Comment: still dose not work when i try the flutter pub get. Should i just try to create a new projekt and copy it over?

Comment: Does table calender depend on syncfusion? If it's bundled inside it, it could cause a conflict. Let me check

Comment: No it doesn't. You and a problem in indentation. Make sure there are no extra spaces. If you create a new project, and copy the files to pubspec then copy the pubspec back, it should work. but better to know the original cause.

Comment: Thanks :-) just pastet all the code in the pubspec..yalm but yea im gonna go ahead and try that

Comment: The whole code is just 36 lines, how are you getting an error in line 41!

Comment: I dont know. Also when i did this the error Message dindt match the Line. I tried starting from scratch and it Worked. Dont really know what went wrong but the same code on a clean sheet worked

Comment: this will happen mostly only when your indentation is not correct, especially for the plugins you add.

Answer (score 0):

**It happent because,**
flutter says that, you put **two time same package** or same name

1. First of all check pubspec.yaml if any package has past 2 time?

- IF YES THEN DELETE 1

2. if not solve then **restart your editor**
3. if not solve then try **flutter clean** & again run **flutter pub get**

I hope your problem will be solve now.